# Iterate through unexpected layers of a nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, iteration

So my situation is as follows. I have a dictionary (shown below) of which I want to iterate through potentially large numbers of iterations, without having to manually define 'for i in dictionary[x][y][...]'. I intend to iterate through each layer and create a large string of html for other purposes. For my dictionary there are potentially unknown amounts of subfolders and files, which is currently making it very hard to iterate through.

**This is my dictionary**

```
{'A Folder': {
    'Another Folder': {
         'Stacked_File': 'secretid'
         'Another Stacked_File': 'anothersecretid'
    }

}, 'Another File':'moreids'...
}
```

**Which I hope to convert to...**

```
<ul>
    <ul>
        <i class="fi-folder"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;A_Folder
    </ul>

    <br>

    <ul>
        <i class="fi-folder"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Another_Folder
        <ul>
            <ul>
                <i class="fi-folder"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Folder_Stacked
                <ul>
                    <ul><i class="fi-page"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Stacked_File
                    <ul><i class="fi-page"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Another_Stacked_File
                </ul>
            </ul>
        </ul>
    </ul>
```

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: check the type and do it recursively

Comment: Sadly I am not entirely sure how I would do that @marcadian . Would you know of any links/sources where I can do further research on it?

Comment: Your example is in regards to filesystems, if you're actually running this code on the system where these files are located you should be able to handle this with a recursive function making use of os.listdir() and os.path.isdir()

Comment: Your example HTML appears to be wrong (`<i>` tags with no content, `<ul>` tags which are unclosed and should be `<li>` also in some cases) and **more importantly** it doesn't correspond in any obvious way to your nested `dict` structure: what happened to `'Another File'` in the HTML version, for example? You should correct the desired output, because it doesn't correspond to the input in any consistent way.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're looking at filesystems, if you're running this code on the system where the filesystem resides, you could handle it with recursion using os.listdir() and os.path.isdir().  Here's a basic example:

```
def iter_folder(folder):
    if not os.path.isdir(folder):
        return
    print "folder: " + folder
    for item in os.listdir(folder):
        if os.path.isdir(item):
            iter_folder(item)
        else:
            print "file: " + item
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard for me to tell what you are actually trying to *do* with the output, but using recursion to flatten the nested dictionary is one good possibility:

```
d = {'A Folder': {
    'Another Folder': {
         'Stacked_File': 'secretid',
         'Another Stacked_File': 'anothersecretid'
    }

}, 'Another File':'moreids'
}

def nested_dict_flattener(d, level=0):
    l = []
    for k,v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, basestring):
            l.append((level, k, v))
        elif isinstance(v, dict):
            l.append((level, k, 'START-FOLDER'))
            l.extend(nested_dict_flattener(v, level+1))
            l.append((level, k, 'END-FOLDER'))
    return l

import pprint
pprint.pprint( nested_dict_flattener(d) )
```

Output:

```
[(0, 'A Folder', 'START-FOLDER'),
 (1, 'Another Folder', 'START-FOLDER'),
 (2, 'Stacked_File', 'secretid'),
 (2, 'Another Stacked_File', 'anothersecretid'),
 (1, 'Another Folder', 'END-FOLDER'),
 (0, 'A Folder', 'END-FOLDER'),
 (0, 'Another File', 'moreids')]
```

Notice what's going on here: your nested `dict`s have been converted to a flat list of `tuple`s. You could then iterate through this list and look for the `START-FOLDER`/`END-FOLDER` markers to decide when to output opening and closing `<ul>` tags.